# ISAPI LoadLibraryFilter error on aspnet_filter.dll

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis, windows-7, iis-7, isapi

I've got a web application that won't run in debugging mode in Visual Studio. Running on Windows 7 computer with IIS 7 installed.

[image: Visual Studio Error]

I've seen the numerous articles on the internet about re-installing the .NET versions, but this has not solved it for me. The project still refuses to compile.

In the Event Log there are several entries when I've started the debug process:

[image: Event Log Error]

With a corresponding entry above it:

[image: Corresponding Event Log Entry]

As stated I have run the .NET registration aspnet_regiis -i for both v2, v4 both 32/64 version of the .NET to no avail.

The error seems to point to the ISAPI filters, which I have tried fiddling with and configuring without success:

[image: ISAPI on dev computer]

I'm now at a loss as to what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message is saying you're loading the 32bit aspnet_isapi.dll in a 64 bit w3wp.exe process.

You can check the application pool "Advanced Settings" for your 64 vs 32bit settings and select the correct one:

[image]

Comment: Hi natemrice - I'd tried this solution several times without success, then - bizarrely - I noticed the AppPool for my web app was using a different AppPool from what it was originally set to. I changed this AppPool to allow 32-bit applications and it solved it. Hoo f'in-rah! This was driving me insane, thanks for your help - guess I should have checked the AppPool more closely, although I've no idea how this setting got changed as the app worked fine up until this error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting, as you mentioned you do registered 32 bit version but your screen shot shows only 64 bit there.

Check my IIS:
[image: My IIS configuration]

Have you checked the configuration manager? I'm wondering would it be possible it was set to compile for certain CPU only.